# Ansible - Enable repo and add PGP key on CentOS 7

Tags: yum, centos7, ansible

I want to automatize deployment of repo to a CentOS 7 machine with Ansible. 
How do I import GPG key of the repository so that `yum` will not ask/prompt me about it?

This is my current solution (but yum still asks):

```
- name: Import repo GPG key
  sudo: yes
  rpm_key:
    key=https://packagecloud.io/gpg.key
    state=present
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Copying the key to `/etc/pki/rpm-gpg/` does not have this problem.

```
- name: Import repo GPG key
  sudo: yes
  copy:
    src=RPM-GPG-KEY
    dest=/etc/pki/rpm-gpg/
    owner=root
    group=root
    mode=644
```